# Why can't a function with an rvalue parameter be forwarded without explicit type cast?

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A{};

void bar(A& a) {
    cout << "in bar A&";
}

void bar(A&& a) {
    cout << "in bar A&&";
}

void foo(A&& a) {
    bar(a);
}

int main()
{
    foo(A());
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints the following:

```
in bar A&
```

Instead of the following:

```
in bar A&&
```

Regarding the [the forwarding problem](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm), `void bar(A&& a)` is a better choice than `void bar(A& a)` in this code. But why doesn't the compiler pick it up? How to properly explain it?

Comment: @Klaus There is no referecen collapsing going on here because there are no templates.

Comment: @Klaus Granted, reference collapsing can happen also outside of templates. But it still does not happen here.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if something has a name, it is an lvalue (you can take its address). Consequently, `a` in `foo` is an lvalue, which explains which `bar` is called then.

Answer (score 2):

when writing

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    bar(a);
}
```

you say that foo receives a rvalue, but as you do not move it to bar, foo remains owner of the `a` thus the only possible bar() call is a `A&`

If you want bar to take ownership, then move it (actually a cast to rvalue...):

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    bar(std::move(a));
}
```

should do what you expect...

EDIT:

Follow up the question why is a not a rvalue when calling bar?

Actually, you do not expect it to be a rvalue; imagine the code was:

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    bar(a);
    bar2(a);
}
```

When looking at this, one would expect a to remain "valid" event if there was a call to bar() right before (this is the usual behaviour in a function regardless a was received as a rvalue or not).

while writing:

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    bar(std::move(a));
    // here you suspect already something goes wrong
    bar2(a); // what is supposed to be 'a' if it was moved?
}
```

In this case you would expect the call to bar2() to be wrong (and would likely not do what you expect)

So here was about why it is a good that the bar(&) is called.

For the "why", the reason is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues.

Comment: Instead of `std::move(a)` one could also write `static_cast<A &&>(a)` which is equivalent. What eludes me is why `a` is not already an rvalue reference (`A &&`) in this context since it is declared as such in the argument list and `bar()` offers a matching overload. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` in the declaration of

```
void foo(A&& a)
```

only has an effect to the outside (caller) of the function, but (almost) not inside the function. To the caller, it says "I only accept rvalues".

Inside the function, there is almost no difference between `&&` and `&`, in particular, `a` is an lvalue. For this reason, `bar(A& a)` is the only viable candidate.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's an unusual way of explaining this. This effect isn't caused by the function call, and if `A&& a` was a (non-parameter) variable, the same thing would happen.